# In which languages does "right" mean both a direction and "correct" (or another positive meaning)?

Tags: etymology, philosophy-of-language, list-of-languages

In Islam right direction symbolize good things and I realize that phenomenon in some languages (English, Russian).

Are there other languages like this and where does this phenomenon come from?

Answer (score 3):

In French, the word [`droit`](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/droit) and its derivatives have several meanings:

> Tournez à droite à l'intersection > Turn **right** at the intersection
>   Il marche dans le droit chemin > He walks in the path of **righteousness**
>   Une ligne droite > A **straight** line

Answer (score 3):

In Spanish, *derecho* can mean either *right* (as in civil rights, *derechos civiles* “civil rights”) or *straight* (as in straight ahead, *sigue el camino todo derecho* “Follow the road straight along”).  The feminine form *derecha* means *right* (as in not left, *gira a la derecha* “Turn right”)